# Raw Syntax Descriptor for a char at POS. What is it?

Tags: syntax

What is the Raw Syntax Descriptor for a char at POS?  Can I have some examples so I can understand what this thing is all about?

Comment: Do `C-h i g (elisp)<RET> i raw syn<TAB>' and read the section. Why do you need to know? What are you trying to do? IME, an approximate understanding of syntax tables is almost always enough (and  those sections fill the gap *when* and only when I really need to dig into very low level details).

Comment: I want to know whether a `(` or `)` occurs within a string, comment or is escaped.

Comment: Please explain the context: I cannot guess what you mean. Are you trying to parse a piece of code? What kind of code? Give an example.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand `syntax`, you need to understand what the `syntax` of a `char` is.  You can find this with how to use the command `C-u C-x =`.  The `syntax` of the same char could be different based on the `mode` in use.

[image: See Syntax of some char]

[image: See Syntax of some other char]

---

`C-x =` runs the command what-cursor-position (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.

It is bound to `C-x =`.

```lisp
(what-cursor-position &optional DETAIL)
```

Print info on cursor position (on screen and within buffer). Also describe the character after point, and give its character code in octal, decimal and hex.  If `what-cursor-show-names` is non-nil, additionally show the name of the character.

For a non-ASCII multibyte character, also give its encoding in the buffer`s selected coding system if the coding system encodes the character safely.  If the character is encoded into one byte, that code is shown in hex.  If the character is encoded into more than one byte, just "..." is shown.

In addition, with prefix argument, show details about that character in *Help* buffer.  See also the command `describe-char`.

Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 27.1.

[back]

Comment: does `syntax-ppss` give `()` in your example?

Comment: What is `C-u C-x =` bound to?

Comment: It is there in my response.   What `Emacs` version are you using and on which OS?

Comment: I have circled things ...  What do  you see there?

Comment: `desribe-char` then.  Have been wondering what  `(nth 3 (syntax-ppss))` does.

Comment: `M-x find-library RET syntax RET` and `M-x occur RET 3 ppss`.  Go to that position and report what do you see.  Take time to think about  information I am giving you.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in Parse-Partial-Sexp State at POS.  I get `418: ((nth 3 ppss) 'string)  473: (nth 3 last)  624: (syntax-ppss--update-stats 3 pt-min pos)`.

Comment: Read that function.  It tells you a lot.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the list returned by `parse-partial-sexp` such as `(9 157 158 34 nil nil 8 nil 166 (146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 157) nil)`.

Comment: How many elements are in that list? Read `C-h f parse-partial-sexp` once again.  There is a numbered list which you cannot miss in the description.